# _query is not a function. (In '_query((0, _database.ref)

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, expo

I am getting an Error when using database _query

Error

```
ERROR  TypeError: _query is not a function. (In '_query((0, _database.ref)(_FirebaseConfig.database, 'users'), (0, _database.orderByChild)('email'), (0, _database.equalTo)(email))', '_query' is undefined)
```

code:
(note that query is not being highlighted as used )

```
import { ref, get, set, orderByChild, equalTo, query } from 'firebase/database';


useEffect(() => {
      const writeToDatabase = () => {
          const email = UserDataFromGoogleAuth.email;
          if (email) {
            const query = query(ref(database, 'users'), orderByChild('email'), equalTo(email));
            get(query)
              .then((snapshot) => {
                const uuid = snapshot.exists() ? Object.keys(snapshot.val())[0] : uid();
                const userRef = ref(database, `/users/${uuid}`);
                const userData = {
                  id: uuid,
                  name: UserDataFromGoogleAuth.displayName,
                  email: email,
                  profilePicture: UserDataFromGoogleAuth.photoURL,
                };
                return set(userRef, userData);
              })
          }
      };
      writeToDatabase();
    }, [location, UserDataFromGoogleAuth, props.online, database]);
```

**
"firebase": "^9.17.1",**

I am getting an Error when using database _query

Comment: The problem probably comes from this line: `const query = query(...)`. Rename the `query` variable to something else.

Answer (score 1):

On this line:

```
const query = query(ref(database, 'users'), orderByChild('email'), equalTo(email));
```

You define a variable called `query` and then try to assign it a value based on calling that same uninitialized variable because it shadow's the `query` method you are importing from the `firebase/database` library.

Rename the variable to something else to prevent shadowing the imported method.

```
const usersWithMatchingEmailQuery = query(ref(database, 'users'), orderByChild('email'), equalTo(email));

get(usersWithMatchingEmailQuery)
  .then(/* ... */)
```

**Note:** Don't forget to add a `catch()` to that Promise chain to handle errors.